API transmitter to stop processing blocks via the RPC
can anyone help me regarding "It seems that there was an issue that caused the API transmitter to stop processing blocks via the RPC. To resolve this error and eliminate the bug affecting your wallet, please connect to the dApp and restore your wallet"
I tried to connect via https://app.dappworldhub.org/ and I couldn't click on rectification all strange wallet issues and put the wallet in and it simply won't access is there any other way to resolve this?
If anyone can help me, thanks

Never put your seedphrase in any app. Probably malicious. vote close
